# Are there ways to visualize the dynamics of a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, graphs

I'm thinking of something like [Gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) that could be applied to the Stack Exchange family of sites. What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the same spirit as amelvin's answer, except this time we're pulling data from the API, so we can ignore all the cruft like 'tag' and 'ago', here's a few interesting ones (Hover for description):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any other suggestions for this is of course welcome

Comment: "programmers" "ever" use "gas" and "station" in comments a lot?

Comment: @YOU The raw data for that one: http://jsfiddle.net/rkV6Q/2/ The word 'gas' appeared 7 times, which is pretty high considering that we're talking about comment's text here

Comment: Any chance you can upload a script that does this? This is sweet.

Comment: On the second cloud you can clearly read "please" "make" "things" "work". :-)

Comment: Have I just not had enough coffee yet, or are c# and .net missing from the 'tags' tag cloud??

Comment: @AakashM Punctuations are stripped, so C# would became C (though C is also gone because of the 'ignore common words' option I think), while .Net become Net I think. In retrospect I think I should rerun the thing with both option off

Comment: Try the "advanced" interface, which lets you use arbitrary strings (such as C#).

Answer (score 7):

[**TagOverflow**](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/), with [code and description on GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#tagoverflow).

[image]

See posts:

- [TagOverflow - interactive exploration of Stack Exchange tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248579/tagoverflow-interactive-exploration-of-stack-exchange-tags)
- [Map of all Stack Exchange sites (except the three biggest)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157976/map-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-except-the-three-biggest)

Comment: You should also answer that question : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122900/visualisation-of-stack-overflow-tag-relationships

Answer (score 4):

Since Gource is by default for commit logs, I ran Gource on the SO log, but even with playing around with the options, I can't get it to give me something decently short.  Rather than do the entire commit history, here's a 2-minute clip of the last month:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ItrdXbIg

Here's a screenshot - the branches are directories and the leaves are files.  In the video, it also shows people flying around representing the users doing the commits.

[image: Gource still image of SO log]

---

Ok, so this is all well and good, but not really about the site topic. (;  I originally thought (read:  didn't bother to check) that their custom log format could be used for visualizing tags - which is why I started to fool around with it at all.

> If you want to use Gource to visualize something other than the supported log formats, there is a pipe ('|') delimited custom log format option:
>
> - timestamp - A unix timestamp of when the update occured.
> - username - The name of the user who made the update.
> - type - initial for the update type - (A)dded, (M)odified or (D)eleted.
> - file - Path of the file updated.
> - colour - A colour for the file in hex (FFFFFF) format. Optional.
>
> Example:  1275543595|andrew|A|src/main.cpp
>
> <sub><sup>http://code.google.com/p/gource/wiki/CustomLogFormat</sup></sub>

Given that log format, I'm not sure I see Gource itself being a good fit for this.

Comment: What does each blob represent?

Comment: @ChrisF, branches are directories, leaves are files.

Comment: Can you upload a video snippet?

Comment: @ripper234, will do tomorrow.

Comment: I wonder if this kind of representation can be applied to tags, where a tag is a node and a line goes to other tags used on the same post, and where the intensity of the line is the number of times the two linked tags are used together.

Comment: @ripper234, video uploaded!

Comment: @Rebecca - what log did you run this on, btw? The video isn't satisfying enough (thanks for uploading though!), I'd like to run Gource myself.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, see my edit regarding their log format and tying this into tags.

Comment: You should play with the Gource's options a bit - it's more fun when you can see names of the main modules/folders, and committers.

Comment: @ripper234, those are on by default - I did play with them to turn them off!  Wayyyyy too busy with them on.

Answer (score 3):

I think a [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net/create) does something interesting along these lines - cutting and pasting the current SO front page text (probably not the best implementation) creates:

[image]

Or even this Tagxedo visualization:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have something like this [Icons of the Web poster](http://www.bamsoftware.com/computers/favicon/), but then with user accounts in stead of icons, and scaled by different variables e.g. reputation (off course), number of answers, number of questions, ...

[image: Icons of the Web Scaled by Alexa reach]

Comment: Cool! I tried this on SO, this is the result: http://goo.gl/mNCEq