# Visualisation of Stack Overflow Tag relationships

Tags: discussion, tags, data-analysis, graphs

Inspired by a previous meta question on [tag trending](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41450/interactive-tag-trend-comparison-page), my 'Sunday afternoon' project was to plot the relationship between the most popular tags on Stack Overflow. The result is quite pretty:

[image: Tag relationship graph]

You can play with [an interactive version on my blog](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/20/visualising-stackoverflow-tag-relationships-with-silverlight.html). I have [published the source code for this control on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342715/Plotting-Circular-Relationships-Graphs-with-Silver). Enjoy!

Comment: Did you look at other approaches to graph layouts besides the circle?

Comment: As pretty as it looks - I'm still not gonna install SilverLight... ;)

Comment: @Lix why not? Do you not have Flash installed either?

Comment: @ChrisF - Sadly in our day and age [one does not simply uninstall flash](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-PJ8cEAcP8xQ/TvV1wNh6cOI/AAAAAAAAFZ8/xauX8pr9N3U/s640/one-does-not-simply-get-off-the-internet.jpg).  Too many sites depend on it.  Silverlight on the other hand, is not a requirement in most cases.  It can produce some great stuff - no doubt - but no sites I use on a  daily/weekly/yearly basis require Silverlight.  Also installing it on Linux makes me feel all icky and hypocritical :P

Comment: @awoodland I must admit, I didn't. I was inspired by various other cicrular relationship graphs I have found online. Can you think of a better way of representing this data?

Comment: I was thinking something like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29 - blow the top 40 tags things and run it for all tags with more than N questions perhaps.

Comment: @awoodland thanks for the reference; the results you link to look very nice. However, I am not sure that method of rendering helps you to draw any conclusions from the data - the main goal of this approach, as described in Wikipedia, is to render the data in an "aesthetically pleasing way". I think the circular representation I have opted for *hopefully* makes it easier to understand the data and draw conclusions from it. Although, it does look pretty too :-P

Comment: @Lix: Neither my iPhone nor my MacBook Pro have Flash installed. I don't miss it.

Comment: @Cody - neither my mobile device nor my personal computers are apple products... I don't miss it. ;)

Comment: Nicely done, @Colin!

Comment: Is there an R interface for the Stack API?

Comment: I don't like that line that runs from `Java` to `JavaScript`, as I'd be willing to bet most of them incorrectly tagged one or the other. `Java` to `Jquery`, although a thinner line, is even more concerning.

Comment: The link in the question is for the blog, not to the blog post showing that plot.