# Choosing the appropriate tags and the influence of this

Tags: support, tags, new-users

Choosing the right tags is good from many point of views, but users (especially new) could be confused somehow.

A question can be debated, straight answered or both. For simplicity, it can be under tag "discussion", "specific tag" or both. Let's say users who are interested in a specific tags could have a very different opinion or answer than other more common users, which, if the case, could lead to a specific direction of discussion, answer accuracy, voting so on. It affects the targeted users too. Also a similar tag could be chosen, but the question is more about choosing between a general or a specific tag.

The question isn't necessary pure for discussion or only specific, it simply could fits both (i.e. asking an opinion about something; this could be labeled "opinion/discussion" or "something/specific" or both).

Choosing one of the next tag combinations, would it makes a difference in the way of influence and which one is recommended and more appropriate: tag1 (discussion), tag 2 (specific tag), tag3 (both)?

*edit* (based on comments)

If you look too technical I will get no answer. Looking a little subjective would help.
I look for answers about how could a tag subjective influence the answers (if I'm permitted). Broad over specific tag, but you could try also a general opinion. If you, based on everyone's own experience, can have a recommendation, it will be good to know it.

If there are no subjective aspects when choosing a tag, you could say that you not encountered one or say nothing, if you like. Other answers/comments could help readers however. Maybe it's hard to understand; I try to clarify a little by this edit.

Comment: Questions can only be discussed on meta sites like this one. On main sites it's just straight up answers, no discussions at all.

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out exactly what your question is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/282094) -  Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36590/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122900/282094

Comment: Can you provide a *specific* example of what you are asking about? Are you talking about meta sites or the main Q&A sites? Because tags like [discussion] and other meta tags are not allowed on the main Q&A sites.

Comment: @ Luuklag - Maybe you are right, but that's the question. I tried a clarification by editing it.

Comment: @ Rob - Useful. Please try read the edit.

Comment: @ Gino Mempin - Some generic example: "operating systems" vs "windows" ... but look at the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit doesn't make things any clearer. I suggest you first familiarize yourself with how the tagging system works. Also provide some real examples, which would be especially helpful as your level of English is fairly basic which makes it extremely hard to read your post.

Comment: @ Luuklang - Does tagging a question "OS" vs. "Windows" (for example) would imply a subjective answer?

Comment: @teo no, tags are not relevant. Stack Exchange discourages discussion due to its nature of being an objective Q&A site. If you want to have a discussion about something, you can try chat, or otherwise, other sites.

Comment: @teo we don't do subjective answers here on SE. If your question is about how an OS should handle event X, then tag the question OS. If you want to know how Windows handles event X, tag your question windows. Tag's don't change what kind of answers you get, the way you write your question does.

Comment: Are you talking about meta questions (questions on meta sites) only? - you talk about the "discussion" tag - presumably the (literal) "[discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)" tag on meta sites). Perhaps make it clearer by providing an example?

Comment: Teo, I think your edit wasn't sufficiently helpful to reopen your question. The edit simply made your question longer, not clearer (for the others); I feel it is a duplicate, and your edit didn't address that, so I vote for this to remain closed - but you can try another edit.

Comment: @ Rob - " Does tagging a question imply only objective answers? " would be better? It's simple and clear, but people may find it too bare. Trying to suggest something in actual form was more problematic for me than good. Should I cut it all and transform it in this short form? Or, should I started a new one? Trying to explain this kind of question in order to make it more clear seems like a vicious circle for me. Any tips?

Comment: @ Luuklag - Subjective questions, subjective answers, maybe not this website style. " ...the way you write your question does...", very true. But this is my question.

Answer (score 2):

Each tag may draw the attention of different people.

Some may watch / search for tag A <sub>(but maybe not tag B)</sub>.

Someone else may follow tag B <sub>(but maybe not tag A)</sub>.

This seems to suggest that if you want to get a wider readership involved — representing a wider gamut of insight, and who in turn are capable of giving you a potentially higher value response — you should use *the combination of all the relevant tags*.

To me, leaving any tags out seems to be analogous to the effort of trying to achieve focus.

But tags are not the right / relevant tool for achieving focus: on the contrary, they are used to broaden the reach — while in a controlled, constructive manner.