# TagOverflow - interactive exploration of Stack Exchange tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I created a graph of tags from Stack Exchange sites (including Stack Overflow, obviously), [**TagOverflow**](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/).

It is a continuation of [my previous project](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki), which have met with a [warm response here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157976/map-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-except-the-three-biggest).

Nodes represent the most popular tags, with their area being proportional to the number of questions with them.

Edges represent relation between tags. Their width is related to the number of questions with both tags, while their shade - how much more often they occur than one should expect by random chance.

Default coloring is due to community detection - automated splitting of a graph into densely connected subgraphs. Positions of the nodes are due to [D3.js force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) (i.e. a spring model, where connected nodes attract each other).

Moreover, especially for Stack Overflow, which is a big place, you can draw conditional graphs. That is, consider only questions with a given tag (e.g. `javascript`). For example, it will count only those occurrences `array`, which happen to be with `javascript`. This tag DO NOT appear for the same reason that the site name does not appear a tag. So, try a tag with your favorite technology! Examples: [JavaScript](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=stackoverflow&size=32&tag=javascript), [Python](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=stackoverflow&size=32&tag=python).

If you are interested in its source or a more detailed description, 
[code and description is on GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#tagoverflow) (also: if you find a bug, the way to go is trough Issues and Pull Requests).

Besides looking at a graph, you can:

- get interesting information per tag (e.g. top questions and users),
- get some statistics (like average score for these tags).

I hope you enjoy it!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Questions:

- are there any findings on SE tags you find insightful and would like to share?
- do you have ideas how to improve its usefulness or niceness to our community?

Comment: poor [tag:r] and [tag:excel] :'(

Comment: This is awesome. Took me a second (sadly) to figure out that the different statistics are under the "coloring" drop-down though. Kudos.

Comment: In the dropdown, `s/at your own wish/at your own risk/`